# Каким оператором добавить данные в ячейку SQL?

Tags: mysql, sql, база-данных, phpmyadmin

Есть ячейка. Пусть с атриботом TEXT.

Каким опетаром можно добавить в нее данные? Не перезаписать, а именно добавить?

Имеем
text1

Добавляем
text2

Результат
text1text2

Спасибо!

Comment: В SQL нельзя "не перзаписать, а добавить". Просто перезаписать нужно значением, содержащим старое значение с добавленным новым.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

пример:

```
UPDATE tab_name SET col_name=CONCAT(col_name,'text2') WHERE id=<id>;
```

Comment: Спасибо, земляк! А что такое id=<id>?

Comment: Рад помочь! :) Вместо `id` надо подставить имя столбца, который одгозначно идентифицирует запись. Обычно это либо `primary key` либо `unique key`. А вместо `<id>` соответствующее значение...

Comment: Блин, не понятно как его наживить. Вот есть INSERT INTO db (name,27_ua,link,date) VALUES ('%name%','%price%','%link%','%date%') ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE 27_ua = %price%;

Comment: Максим, здравствуйте. Вот полный вопрос :( https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/846483/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-sql-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%81. Я так и не разобрался.

Comment: @Lebedev, здравствуйте. Я не совсем понимаю суть нового вопроса...