# Как дополнить SQL запрос?

Tags: mysql, sql, база-данных, phpmyadmin

Есть такой SQL запрос:

```
INSERT INTO db (name,f,link,time) VALUES ('%name%','%price%','%link%','%date%');
```

(name - PRIMARY KEY)

Задача такая. Дополнить запрос таким образом, что бы в "f" и "time" добавлялись новые данные, не перезапись новыми, а именно добавлялись.

Так например при первом запрос
f=text1
time=15:58:00

При втором
f=text2
time=15:59:00

Результат
f=text1|text2
time=15:58:00|15:59:00

Answer (score 3):

Вы можете со мной не согласиться, но как бы вам не хотелось - делать это неправильно. Вы скорее всего еще мало понимаете в предметной области и хотите быстро решить проблему. Если и делать так, то делать это не при insert (инсерт всегда добавляет строку), а при update. И делать это можно через триггер

```
CREATE TRIGGER `my_super_trigger` before update ON `table_name`
FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
  SET NEW.f =  CONCAT(OLD.f, '|', NEW.f);
END;
```

Т.е. теоретически ваша цель достижима, но делать так скорее всего в вашей задаче - не верно. Т.е. делать надо как-то иначе, по ситуации.

PS А ответ Timur Milovanov про INSERT INTO...ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE... еще лучше!

Comment: Согласен. Во-первый, странный запрос. Для описанной проблемы не очень подходит СУБД. Insert логически должен всегда добавлять запись, Update -- обновлять запись. Во-вторых, можно посмотреть на конструкцию `INSERT INTO...ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE...` (похоже на Oracle#merge). https://stackoverflow.com/a/15875387/2351996. Но в mysql там есть особенности (описаны в ответах по ссылке)

Comment: тут задача индивидульная. Это будет уже рабочая база. И этот формат БД уже обдуман. Задача просто составить запрос :)

Comment: @Lebedev *Задача просто составить запрос* Внимательнейшим образом прочтите комментарий от **Timur Milovanov**. То, что он предлагает "во-вторых", есть единственно правильное решение. А использование триггера на этой задаче есть не более чем натягивание трусов через голову - оно вроде и получается, а вроде и ни фига... собственно косяк-то вылезет уже при вставке первой записи.

Comment: @TimurMilovanov Полагаю, будет правильно, если Вы преобразуете свой комментарий в ответ. Дополнив его исправленным текстом запроса, само собой.

Comment: Спасибо за совет, вынес текст из комментария в *ответ*

Answer (score 1):

В некоторых СУБД (например Oracle) существуют `INSTEAD OF TRIGGER` которые можно навесить на представления (`VIEW`) и вместо `INSERT INTO VIEW_NAME ...` делать `UPDATE BASE_TABLE ...`, **НО**:

1. ЕМНИП MySQL не поддерживает `INSTEAD OF TRIGGERS`
2. ваша модель данных нарушает одно из главных правил первой нормальной формы: [`"Каждое пересечение строки и столбца содержит ровно одно значение из соответствующего домена (и больше ничего)"`](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9F%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%8F_%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BC%D0%B0%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%8F_%D1%84%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BC%D0%B0#%D0%9E%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5) - с ростом БД и нагрузки это вылезет в непреодолимые, искусственно созданные проблемы. Самое неприятное в этом подходе - это то, что вначале все замечательно работает, а когда начинаются проблемы, то приходится менять слишком много всего как в БД, так и в приложениях, чтобы от этого косяка полноценно избавиться. Не забываем еще о предстоящей миграции этих данных в нормальное представление. В общем я по работе уже несколько раз сталкивался с таким подходом и каждый раз это рано или поздно превращалось в серьезную проблему.

**Вывод:** используйте реляционную БД как реляционную БД и не надо пытаться использовать программистские шаблоны в БД если они не совместимы с ее идеологией.

Comment: а разве у автора подразумевается хранение ненормализованных данных? разве `f=text1|text2` - это одна запись или всё же таким образом автор обозначил 2 записи в одном столбце?

Comment: @Anatol, судя по контексту, речь идёт об одной записи

Answer (score 1):

Для описанной проблемы не очень подходит СУБД. Как минимум потому что `INSERT` логически должен всегда добавлять запись, `UPDATE`... ну, вы поняли.

Класические приёмы аудита на уровне СУБД предполагают вставку в отельную таблицу значений полей ДО/ПОСЛЕ `UPDATE`-изменения. Эти приёмы можно сделать через триггеры (описано с соседнем ответе).

Также можно посмотреть на конструкцию `INSERT INTO...ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE...` (похоже на Oracle#merge). Но в mysql там есть особенности (описаны [здесь](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/393679/converting-an-oracle-merge-query-into-mysql-mysql-query/15875387#15875387))

Answer (score 0):

```
INSERT INTO db (name, f, link, time) VALUES
  ('%name%','%price%','%link%','%date%')
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE
  f = CONCAT(f, '|', VALUES(f)), time = CONCAT(time, '|', VALUES(time));
```

Но полностью поддерживаю предыдущих ораторов, что так делать не стоит